# How to start a timer for 10 minutes and than disable the button after the timer using javascript

Tags: javascript, button, timer, countdowntimer

[The screenshot of the timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixyVa.png)
I am working on a software and I want to disable the button after the timer gets finish. The timer have been added but cannot hide the button after the timer finishes.

The following is the html of the timer.

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">If you want to cancel the hiring you can <br /> Time remaining <span id="time"></span> minutes!    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel " class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button" />
                    </div>
```

The following is the javascript of the timer.

```
<script>
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var start = Date.now(),
            diff,
            minutes,
            seconds;
        function timer() {
            // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since
            // startTimer() was called
            diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

            // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
            minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
            seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (diff <= 0) {
                // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
                // example 05:00 not 04:59
                start = Date.now() + 1000;
            }
        };
        // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
        timer();
        setInterval(timer, 1000);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried and explain specifically what is not working.

Comment: `<div class="form-group ">
    <input type="submit" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel " class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button" />
  </div>` 
I have just kept a button. Now I want to start a timer for 10 minutes and after that 10 minutes timer this button gets hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById("disablethis").disabled  = true;
}, 1000 * 60 * 10);
```

Comment: Hey I tried it by this javascript function but it is not working.

Comment: @sikanderkhursheed I hope that you didnt just copy and paste that in the hopes that it would work.

Comment: No I didn't copied it as a whole, I changed it according to my code requirement.